# How Can I edit and save at same place any Text file present in my computer using javascript?

Tags: javascript

want these things when a function call :
1.Open a text file (not visible to user)
2.Select a Text which is to be change 
3.change the text 
4.And save it at same place.

Comment: Questions asking for code must **demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved**. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the *expected* results. See also: [Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist)

Answer (score 3):

This is not possible in JavaScript. JavaScript is sandboxed by the browser and doesn't have access to the local computer.

Also, what you're trying to do sounds dodgy, and may well be the exact reason why it's sandboxed.

Comment: Javascript is not exclusively in browser and html 5 also provides [file API](http://www.w3.org/TR/FileAPI/).

Comment: I know, but looking at the question I reckon he wants to do it in the browser.